# Automatic shipping calculation based on postal code

Tags: virtuemart, joomla-1.5

I am using Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart 1. I want to setup automatic shipping based on postcodes/location. For example if a customer lives in the postcode DH2 then they will have to pay a delivery fee of £1.50. Other fares for other postcodes could be higher or lower. I want to be able to do this automatically. Can anyone help?

Comment: I doubt anyone on here is using Joomla 1.5 (ancient) and VirtueMart 1 (ancient). Please try doing some research and above all, please consider upgrading to the latest version of Joomla

Comment: I've been researching this for weeks and found nothing. Theres a section to enter Zip codes but it doesn't work with English post codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GJC's plugin does the job. But this is using Joomla 2.5 and VM3. Still looking for an answer for 1.5, but might end up taking all sites to later Joomlas/VMs anyway.  - http://www.gjcwebdesign.com/joomla-downloads/virtuemart-20-postcode-zip-code-shipping-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

The Standard Shipping module worked for me in Australia (see below).

UK postcodes are a little different and you may have to search the downloads and forums on the Virtuemart website for a UK postcode compatible version of the module.

1. Create a Shipper.
2. Create Shipping Rates as required as per the example below.

[image]

Comment: Because I'm using Virtuemart 1 and Joomla 1.5 I doubt theres any downloads for it anymore. We're looking into the newer versions. I don't think the standard module will work for English postcodes since we have ones like "DH1 4BY", not just numbers which it seems is what its built for. I can stop users registering who don't have certain postcodes with JavaScript, but I just need the automatic delivery by postcode.

Comment: No I am capable of looking myself